# Eloquent with sub query, the sum is wrong Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, database, join, subquery

Here is the table detail

1. suppliers:
   id,
   name,
2. purchases:
   id,
   supplier_id,
   total
3. payments:
   id,
   paymentable_id,
   paymentable_type,
   paid

I am trying to generate payment sum with respect to purchase associate with a supplier. Also purchase sum associate with a supplier. But I am having wrong result, I have found that sometimes it's not getting sum of purchases, and payments tables, and sometimes it's not.

```
Supplier::select('*')->leftJoinSub(function ($query){
                $query->select(
                    'supplier_id',
                    DB::raw('sum(total) as purchased_total'),
                    DB::raw(
                        "
                        (select sum(paid) from payments where payments.paymentable_id = purchases.id)
                        "
                    )
                )
                ->from('purchases')
                ->groupBy('supplier_id');
            }, 'pu', 'pu.supplier_id', '=', 'suppliers.id')
            ->fromCompany()
            ->groupBy('suppliers.id')
            ->get();
```